# PHP preg_match is mismatching a curly apostrophe with other types of curly quotes. How to avoid?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have the following variable content:

`$content_content = '“I can’t do it, she said.”';`

I want to do a preg_match for every "word" in that, including the contractions, so I use preg_match as follows:

```
 if (preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9’]+)/', $content_content, $matches))
 {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
    echo '</pre>';
 }
```

However, it seems by including ’ in the regular expression, it's also trapping the curly double quotes, as the above command outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ��
            [1] => I
            [2] => can’t
            [3] => do
            [4] => it
            [5] => she
            [6] => said
            [7] => ��
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ��
            [1] => I
            [2] => can’t
            [3] => do
            [4] => it
            [5] => she
            [6] => said
            [7] => ��
        )

)
```

How can I include ’ without it also including the “ and ”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the "fancy" apostrophe you're using inside the character set is treated in its binary form; you need to enable Unicode mode using its respective [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9’]+)/u', $content_content, $matches)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/229718)